# Is there any way to get an enumeration of components used on a page in the React dev tools?

Tags: reactjs, components, react-devtools

I would like to know which of my components are being rendered on a page - e.g. for general documentation purposes. All this info is already present in the React Dev tools "Components" tab.

However, I have tried to copy this info without success. Is there a way to get e.g. this UI in text form (maybe like the `tree` command output but not necessarily like that):

[image]

EDIT: One of the things I've tried was using this but the output is lacking: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-component-hierarchy
It relies on source code parsing (I guess). The React dev tools, however, already have all this info (correctly) - it would be great if there was a way to do it through the dev tools.